# Automated Visio Database Model Diagrams

Tags: database, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013, diagrams, modeling

Is it possible to automatically create a Visio database model diagram from a edge list or some sort of source/target file? I am looking to automatically create some sort of data flow diagram in Visio based off of source and target information that could be stored in a database table. This would be in Visio 2013, as I know there have been a lot of changes recently.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse engineering of database diagrams was removed in Visio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that this functionality was removed from the Visio 2013 product I observe that this was a good move as it made the ERD designer simpler and more usable for ERD designers.

MS Access can be used to reverse engineering a database and generate detailed Schema diagrams. You can also use Entity Framework in Visual Studio for a more coder friendly ERD design tool. I personally never felt Visio was ever very good at this esspecially when there are so many other tools out there that are so much better at generating ERDs. Visio's primary use case is the visual design of diagrams and models. The overhead of supporting all the Meta data elements supplied by reverse engineering an actual database made starting a new ERD diagram from visio far to cumbersome for simple data modelers to get a new design off the ground.